# SQL Display time hours:minutes only

Tags: t-sql, time

I'm converting an int to time using the following code, but the result comes out as 09:00:00.000000 etc.

```
(cast(CAST(t0.U_ProdStartTime / 100 as varchar) + ':' + CAST(t0.U_ProdStartTime % 100 as varchar) 
as time)) 
AS 'Start Time',

(cast(CAST(t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdTime / 100 as varchar) + ':' + CAST(t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdTime % 100 as varchar) 
as time))
AS 'End Time',
```

I want it to only display 09:00:00?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer.

Comment: What description does it require?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure where to put this

Comment: Use this statement in your select and replace GETDATE() with you datetime field.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the 'FORMAT' to do this easily

```
 FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(t0.U_ProdStartTime,'hh:mm') AS StartTime,FORMAT(t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdTime,'hh:mm') AS EndTime 
FROM YourTable AS [to]
```

or if u need seconds u can use

```
 SELECT FORMAT(t0.U_ProdStartTime,'hh:mm:ss') AS StartTime,FORMAT(t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdTime,'hh:mm:ss') AS EndTime 
 FROM YourTable AS [to]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one method I know

```
declare @t int
set @t=345
select convert(varchar(10),
(cast(CAST(@t / 100 as varchar) + ':' + CAST(@t % 100 as varchar) 
as datetime)) ,108)
AS 'Start Time'
```

Result

```
Start Time
----------
03:45:00
```